# Task/issue tracking system with command-line interface

Tags: task-tracking

Are the any task tracking systems with command-line interface?

Here is a list of features I'm interested in:

- Simple task template
  Something like plain-text file with property:type pairs, for example:

> ```
> description:string  
> some-property:integer required
> ```

- command line interface
  for example:

> ```
> // Creates task
> <task tracker>.exe -create {description: "Foo", some-property: 1}   
> // Search for tasks with description field starting from F
> <task tracker>.exe -find { description: "F*" }
> ```

- XCopy deployment
  It should not require to install heavy DBMS
- Multiple users support
  So it's not just a to-do list for a single person

Comment: What kind of task do you mean? Bug-Tickets and Feature-Requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ditz is a simple, light-weight distributed issue tracker designed to work
>   with distributed version control systems like darcs and git.

Ditz: http://web.archive.org/web/20121212202849/http://gitorious.org/ditz

Also cloned here: https://github.com/jashmenn/ditz

Comment: almost what I want. but datamodel is not extensible

Comment: The link is dead. Does it moved somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

Interesting idea; the closest thing I have heard of is [todo.txt](http://todotxt.com/).

Alternatively, you could roll your own by just using a database (e.g. sqllite) and SQL. Optionally, write a wrapper script that parses your plain-text file and command-line options, and generates the corresponding SQL.

Comment: My understanding is that you can't use todo.txt on different projects. Seems like it requires you to store the location (TODO_DIR="path/to/todofile") of your single todo.txt in a centralized todo.cfg file. Or?

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen [ticgit](http://github.com/schacon/ticgit/wikis). It sounds like it might do just what you guys are after.

Comment: Interesting thing, I'll take a closer look

Comment: Here is a link to the *current* (summer2014) active fork: https://github.com/jeffWelling/ticgit

Answer (score 2):

## Erlangs Ticket System

Created by Peter Högfeldt in 1986. This is the ticket system that was used in the Erlang distribution.

Source: [Joe Armstrong's blog](https://joearms.github.io/published/2014-06-25-minimal-viable-program.html)

Answer (score 1):

http://roundup.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

@Peter Hilton,

I'm going to create such system. So I'm wondering whether such system exists. General idea is to keep it as simple as possible: command line utility to manage tasks & simple server wit REST interface. I used dozen different task tracking system and come to conclusion that I don't need fancy UI. It should be like Subversion - you can happily work with command-line based svn.exe

Answer (score 1):

I've abused the `cal` and `calendar` commandline tools regularly for this type of task.

Answer (score 1):

[ciss](http://codespeak.net/ciss/) issue tracker is a simple commandline tool for managing your ISSUES.txt file.

Comment: Ciss looks dead.

Answer (score 0):

Fogbugz has a [Command Line Client](http://support.fogcreek.com/default.asp?W840).

Comment: Nope, fogbugz is to heavy, I'm looking for something like svn

Comment: That's been deprecated. Came here looking for something like [this](https://developers.kilnhg.com/Code/FogBugz/Group/FogBugzPy/File/README.txt?rev=tip), turns out the replacement is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Pitz](http://pitz.tplus1.com/) and [Bugs Everywhere](http://bugseverywhere.org/be/show/HomePage).

Comment: Both links are dead.

Answer (score 0):

I use [org-mode](http://www.org-mode.org) with emacs in terminal mode (emacs -nw).

Answer (score 0):

We have used a few tools earlier. We now use a GitHub private repository to maintain various developer TBD lists (as .md files) and issue tracking because of the following advantages:

- Developers are already using GitHub and they don't need to learn anything new.
- Developers can use whatever tool they are comfortable with to maintain TBD list; command line or graphical editors, GitHub web interface or plenty of mobile clients
- Markdown support
- Reliable backup
- Merging and revision history
- Flexible file organization for different projects and modules